# Create an executable out of linking only with CMake

Tags: c, assembly, cmake

I want CMake to issue the following command, or one equivalent to it, while producing my `kernel` executable

```sh
mipsel-linux-gnu-ld -o kernel hello.o termprint.o crtso.o libumps.o -G 0 -nostdlib -T ./umps/umpscore.ldscript
```

Note that the above command completely skips `gcc` invocation on `kernel` -- it only runs the linker. In order to replicate that command with CMake, I am attempting to define the following rules

```
file(WRITE null.c "")

add_executable(kernel null.c)
target_link_options(kernel PRIVATE ${LDFLAGS})
target_link_libraries(kernel phase0 crtso libumps termprint)
```

but the issue is that the generated `Makefile` issues a compilation step to produce `kernel`, while I only want to do linkage

```sh
$ make VERBOSE=1 kernel

# Lots of output
...
mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc   -rdynamic -G 0 -nostdlib -T /home/acsor/Software/BiKaya/src/umps/umpscore.ldscript CMakeFiles/kernel.dir/null.c.o CMakeFiles/phase0.dir/src/phase0.c.o CMakeFiles/crtso.dir/src/umps/crtso.S.o CMakeFiles/libumps.dir/src/umps/libumps.S.o CMakeFiles/termprint.dir/src/termprint.c.o  -o kernel
...

# Link errors follow
```

How do I do what I want in a CMake-style way? You can find my CMake setup [here](https://gist.github.com/newnone/a4e0e12c0c410f15e3b671f0419ab3ad).

Comment: Where is the compilation step? GCC can also be used for linking.

Comment: are `hello.o termprint.o crtso.o libumps.o` also compiled by the CMake file? Please show the CMake for that as well.

Comment: [Here it is](https://gist.github.com/newnone/a4e0e12c0c410f15e3b671f0419ab3ad). I was thinking about tweaking the `CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE` variable, any cons to that?

Comment: Are all those `.c.o` extension correct?...

Comment: @Acsor maybe the cleanest way would be to create a toolchain file? Have a look [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling).

Answer (score 0):

No need to make separate object libraries for each C file. Just do something like this:

```
add_executable(kernel ${SRC}/phase0.c ${UMPS_SRC}/crtso.S ${UMPS_SRC}/libumps.S ${SRC}/termprint.c)
set_target_property(TARGET kernel APPEND PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS -rdynamic -G 0 -nostdlib -T ${UMPS_SRC}/umpscore.ldscript)
```